# Who reads /etc/resolv.conf?

Tags: networking, dns, networkmanager, resolv.conf

My Centos 7 server doesn't resolve domain names properly. From what I see, in modern Linux systems `/etc/resolv.conf` is often generated with `dhclient`,  `dnsmasq` or `Network Manager`.

Thus I have a general theoretical question about network stack in modern Linuxes:

Who is responsible for reading `/etc/resolv.conf`? What players (services or kernel subsystems) are involved in domain name resolution?

**SHORT ANSWER:** [Arch linux manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Domain_name_resolution) says that high-level configuration of  domain name resolution [is done in](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/nsswitch.conf.5) `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and relies on Name Service Switch `glibc` API.

`glibc` uses `nss-resolve` function for sending DNS requests to DNS servers.

Normally on modern CentOS systems `nss-resolve` [relies upon](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/nss-resolve.8) `systemd-resolved` service. If `/etc/resolv.conf` was generated by something like `dhclient-script`, `systemd-resolved` reads it and works in a compatibility mode, emulating behaviour of older systems like `BIND` DNS client.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## DNS client libraries do.

C libraries contain DNS clients that wrap up name-to-address lookups in the DNS protocol and hand them over to proxy DNS servers to do all of the grunt work of query resolution.  There are a lot of these DNS clients.  The one that is in the main C runtime library of your operating system will very likely be the one from ISC's BIND.  But there are a whole load of others from Daniel J. Bernstein's `dns` library through c-ares to adns.

Although several of them contain their own native configuration mechanisms, they generally have a BIND library compatibility mode where they read `resolv.conf`, which is the configuration file for the ISC's BIND C client library.

The NSS is layered on top of this, and is configured by `nsswitch.conf`.  One of the things that NSS lookups can invoke internally is the DNS client, and `nsswitch.conf` is read by the NSS code in the C library to determine whether and where lookups are handed to the DNS client and how to deal with the various responses.

(There is a slight complication to this idea caused by the Name Services Cache Dæmon, nscd.  But this simply adds an extra upper-layer client in the C library, speaking an idiosyncratic protocol to a local server, which in its turn acts as a DNS client speaking the DNS protocol to a proxy DNS server.  `systemd-resolved` adds similar complications.)

`systemd-resolved`, `NetworkManager`, `connman`, `dhcpcd`, `resolvconf`, and others adjust the BIND DNS client configuration file to switch DNS clients to talk to different proxy DNS servers on the fly.  This is out of scope for this answer, especially since there are plenty of answers on this WWW site already dealing with the byzantine details that such a mechanism involves.

The more traditional way of doing things in the Unix world is to run a proxy DNS server either on the machine itself or on a LAN.  Hence what the FreeBSD manual says about normally configured systems, where the default action of the DNS client library in the absence of `resolv.conf` matches what Unix system administrators normally have, which is a proxy DNS server listening on 127.0.0.1.  (The FreeBSD manual for `resolv.conf` is actually doco that *also* originates from ISC's BIND, and can of course also be found where the BIND DNS client library has been incorporated into other places such as the GNU C library.)

## Further reading

- Daniel J. Bernstein. *[The `dns` library](https://cr.yp.to/djbdns/blurb/library.html)*.  cr.yp.to.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2017). *[What DNS name qualification is](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-name-qualification.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2004). *[What DNS query resolution is](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-query-resolution.html)*
  .  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2001). *[The Big Picture for "djbdns"](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/djbdns-big-picture.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2000). *["content" and "proxy" DNS servers.](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/dns-server-roles.html)*  Frequently Given Answers.

Answer (score 7):

From the far better FreeBSD man page, [resolv.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?resolv.conf):

```
 The resolver configuration file contains information that is read by the
 resolver routines the first time they are invoked by a process.

 On a normally configured system this file should not be necessary.  The
 only name server to be queried will be on the local machine, the domain
 name is determined from the host name, and the domain search path is
 constructed from the domain name.
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/resolv.conf` is read by *libc calls that perform host name resolution. This is primarily `getaddrinfo` and the deprecated `gethostbyname`.

If these functions are passed a DNS name, then they do these things in the following order:

1. Try to resolve the host name locally, that is by reading `/etc/hosts`.
2. If this fails, then query the DNS servers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
3. If this also fails, then the host name cannot be resolved.

Since you mention *dnsmasq*: This is a DNS server which runs locally. So, on many modern Linux distros, the `/etc/resolv.conf` only points to `127.0.0.1` (this is where the local dnsmasq listens on). dnsmasq is then configured to forward the queries Internet DNS servers; dnsmasq is configured by Network Manager upon connecting to the Internet.

Comment: Those aren't system calls, those are *libc functions.

Comment: @JoshuaRLi sure, I edited it.